# Nuxt child transitions not working in some cases

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, css-transitions

I have an app with a simple child/grandchild 2-layer nesting and I'm trying to do transitions on both layers of nuxt-child(ren). Mysteriously, the transition works fine on the grandchild but for some reason doesnt work on the child even though its the same transition. I can inspect in the inspector and verify that its applying the classes correctly. What ends up happening is that instead of a smooth transition for 500ms, it just pauses for 500ms and renders the child page.

[Here's the simple repo](https://github.com/udit99/animating_child_pages) demonstrating the issue. [Here's the code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wildflower-ol6d6) with a deployed app.

Here's how I'm doing transitions:

Template:

```
    <transition name="jade" mode="out-in">
      <nuxt-child></nuxt-child>
    </transition>
```

Style:

```
.jade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.jade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.jade-enter, .jade-leave-to
{
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, there are two ways you can solve this

- Using `transition` property in individual pages ([Nuxt Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/transition/))

*/src/index.vue*

```
export default {
  transition: {
    name: 'jade',
    mode: 'out-in'
  }
}
```

- Set `pageTransition` in `nuxt.config.js`, which will apply globally to all the transition components ([Nuxt Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-transition/#the-pagetransition-property))

*/nuxt.config.js*

```
export default {
  pageTransition: 'jade'
  // or
  pageTransition: {
    name: 'jade',
    mode: 'out-in'
  }
}
```

Here's my [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-nuxtchild-transition-ohx5b?file=/pages/index/_foo.vue) using `transition` property